# Should we have a Q/A on setting PATH and environment variables?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Questions about setting environment variables and/or the `PATH` are [very](https://superuser.com/search?q=environment%20variable) [common](https://superuser.com/search?q=set%20path), I guess, and in most cases the answers are the same.

There is a [CW answer on how to set the PATH on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/236167/how-do-i-append-user-defined-environment-variables-to-the-system-variable-path-in/236172#236172), but as far as I've seen there's none for any Unix/Linux or even OS X.

So should we have a Community Q/A for this topic, possibly covering all major operating systems?

I've never done that here, still a bit new to the whole system, so I'm waiting for any input. (Or should I just go ahead and ask with the [community-faq-proposed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq-proposed) tag?)

---

Just a few questions/answers on that topic I found:

- [Confused about setting environment variables](http://Confused%20about%20setting%20environment%20variables)
- [how to set path environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/174720/how-to-set-path-environment-variable)
- [Environment variables Windows7](https://superuser.com/questions/163891/environment-variables-windows7/163898#163898)
- [Where does $PATH get set in  OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard)
- [How to set PATH to run programs outside of default path?](https://superuser.com/questions/185908/how-to-set-path-to-run-programs-outside-of-default-path)
- [Add directory to $PATH if it's not already there](https://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there)
- ...

Comment: I'd say go ahead @slhck ;-) Also note that you can write a blog post about it, so you can point to that as a future reference

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I started the question. Looking forward to good answers :)

#### [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

> Questions about
>
> - setting environment variables
> - the `PATH`
>
> are very common here, and in most
>   cases the answers are very similar to
>   each other. In the future it would be
>   nice to have a good Q/A for this.
>
> So the question is: **How do I set the
>   executable `PATH` and other
>   environment variables  on major
>   operating systems?**
>
> A good answer would include a simple
>   explanation of what environment
>   variables and especially `PATH` mean
>   to the OS, as well as simple
>   guidelines on how to set them
>   accordingly.